# iphone's nsxmlparser parsing RSS causes encoding problems

Tags: iphone, encoding, utf-8, nsxmlparser, diacritics

Im working on simle RSS reader. This reader loads data from internet via this code:

```
NSXMLParser *rss = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/50405236.rss"]];
```

My problem is with encoding. RSS 2.0 file is supposed to be UTF8 encoded according to encoding attribute in XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

So when I download URLs content **I get text truncated after first occurance** of char with diacritics, example: ľ š č ť ž ý á í é, etc.

I tried to solve the problem by downloading URL as UTF8 string, I used this code:

```
NSString *rssXmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.macblog.sk/rss.xml"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil]; 
NSData *rssXmlData = [rssXmlString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Did not help. Thanx for your responses.

Comment: So I SOLVED this issue myself. So the problem was in this method parser:foundCharacters:, I had to read documentation in more detail: 

The parser object may send the delegate several parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an element. Because string may be only part of the total character content for the current element, you should append it to the current accumulation of characters until the element changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MWFeedParser on GitHub](http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser), it's an open source RSS/Atom feed parser I've released and it makes reading and parsing web feeds extremely easy.

There's a simple demo app too which shows how easy it is to implement.

Hope this might be of some use!

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for good tip. But now im using Three20 framework and there is build in parser..